# Replace string value from dynamically added spinner

Tags: android

I need to replace the selected value in a string variable.  This is my Spinner adapter, which I have added dynamically:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        helptextList);
                spinnerAdapter
                        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                sr.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
                spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                sr.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        mSelectedSpinnerValue += helptextList.get(arg2) + ",";
                    }
```

I get the selected values successfully. Now I need to add all values using ",". My problem is this: while selecting the value second time, it's getting added in the same string, but I want to replace the old value with the new value. Can anyone please suggest how to get the updated values in the string variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi The Following Code will Help You...

```
String[] helptextList=null;

    int i=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        helptextList ="a~b~c".split("~");
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                helptextList);
        Spinner sr=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sample);
        spinnerAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sr.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        sr.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                    int pos, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(i!=0 && !parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().endsWith(","))
                helptextList[pos]=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()+",";
                i++;
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
```

I checked,if(i!=0) this check for first time.If You select the Item,it will automatically update for next time.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
mSelectedSpinnerValue += helptextList.get(arg2) + ",";
```

to:

```
mSelectedSpinnerValue = helptextList.get(arg2) + ",";
```

have 3 variables with initial values as:

```
String sp1="Yes", sp2="NO", sp3="Got";
```

and in onitem selected:

```
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {

                    sp1= helptextList.get(arg2);
                    mSelectedSpinnerValue=String.format("(%s,%s,%s)",sp1,sp2,sp3);
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but my spinner is dynamically added, take an example: there are three spinners i need to get all the default values at the first time(Yes,No,Got), if i change the value in any of the spinner it will update in my String like(No,No,Got)..

Comment: That values also a dynamic values, may be it have four values and four spinners..

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `+` sign in

```
mSelectedSpinnerValue += helptextList.get(arg2) + ",";
```

What you are doing right now is keep concatenating the already existing `String` with the new one that you select.

Once you remove the `+` sign it will set the selected value in `mSelectedSpinnerValue`

Answer (score 0):

Use:-

```
mSelectedSpinnerValue = helptextList.get(arg2) + ",";
```

Instead of :-

```
mSelectedSpinnerValue += helptextList.get(arg2) + ",";
```